# Who is exempt from obtaining a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, eu, spouses, salvadoran-citizens

I am British, my husband is from El salvador. We want to visit frankfurt, madrid., crete and italy for a few days only before going to UK . Do we need any visas like a tourist visa or a schengen visa?

Comment: The alleged duplicate question concerns a Jordanian, while this one concerns a Salvadoran. El Salvador is an Annex II country, whose nationals don't need a visa for short stays in any case, and the answers to the alleged duplicate do not consider that possibility. The correct answer to this question is *no,* while the correct answer to that one is *yes.*  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Your husband is exempt from both [Schengen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Citizens_of_.27Annex_II.27_countries_and_territories) and [UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_Kingdom#Non-visa_nationals) visa requirements on the virtue of being a citizen of El Salvador. In addition, he may take the `EU Citizens/Family members` lane when flying into each country with yourself.